# How can I select the top 10 from a dictionary in .NET?

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary which is sorted like this:

```
var sortedDict = (from entry in dd 
                  orderby entry.Value descending  select entry
                 ).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

How can I select top 10 from this sorted dictionary?

Comment: Increase Acception Rate. Accept the answer which help you to get out from problem & increase your knowledge

Answer (score 28):

As you mention descending in your query, I assume that you need Last 10 Occurences. If so

```
  var sortedDict = (from entry in dd orderby entry.Value descending select entry)
                     .Take(10)
                     .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value) ;


  var sortedDict = dd.OrderByDescending(entry=>entry.Value)
                     .Take(10)
                     .ToDictionary(pair=>pair.Key,pair=>pair.Value);
```

If you need first 10, just remove `descending` and it will work fine.

```
var sortedDict = (from entry in dd orderby entry.Value select entry)
                     .Take(10)
                     .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value) ;


var sortedDict = dd.OrderBy(entry=>entry.Value)
                     .Take(10)
                     .ToDictionary(pair=>pair.Key,pair=>pair.Value);
```

Answer (score 5):

Since you ordered your dictionary `descending`, then `Take`ing the first 10 results will be selecting the `TOP` 10:

```
var sortedDict = (from entry in dd 
                  orderby entry.Value descending  
                  select entry
                  ).Take(10)
                  .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Take(10)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [Take()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) method:

```
var sortedDict = (
    from entry in dd 
    orderby entry.Value descending
    select entry)
    .Take(10)
    .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var sortedDict = (from entry in dd orderby entry.Value descending select entry)
                 .Take(10).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

This would be more efficient if you take 10 first and then convert them to dictionary. In cases where its vice versa it will convert all of them to dictionary first and then take 10 out of it. This will effect efficiency if we have a large list to choose from.