# ASP.NET how to sort a dictionary using from phrase?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sorting, dictionary

My question revolves around the "from" phrase when getting a List or Dictionary.
An example is:

```
(From entry In dicItemImportance Order By entry.Value.prpImportanceValue Descending Select entry).ToList()
```

I need to understand the syntax of this type of phrase, but cannot find documentation for this usage.

1. Is there a description of this type of phrase in the ASP.NET documentation?
2. what are valid terms following the 'Select' word?
3. how can I sort by two values one ASC and one DESC?
4. I have tried to populate a Dictionary(Of String, clsItemImportance) it appears the number of arguments is not correct for 'ToDictionary'. Any advice?

Any examples or links will be appreciated -- especially VB.net.
I thank you in advance.

Comment: Have a read of this: [Basic LINQ Query Operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx)

Comment: There is the `.OrderBy(<expression>).ThenBy(<expression>)` methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for responding -- your answers were very helpful.
I am answering my own question based on the comments received.

Q#1 and #2 was answered by Matt Wilko.
And I found: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384607(v=vs.110).aspx

Q#3 was answered by OneFineDay.
And: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385197(v=vs.110).aspx

Q#4 Found this answer by converting C# code to VB code:

```
Dim sortedDict = (From entry In ddOrder By entry.Value Descendingentry).Take(10).ToDictionary(Function(pair) pair.Key, Function(pair) pair.Value)
```

Reference to the C# question/code: 
[How can I select the top 10 from a dictionary in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256652/how-can-i-select-the-top-10-from-a-dictionary-in-net)